# Evaluating the modulus squared of a spinor chain with different number of spinor and anti-spinors

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, trace

I want to evaluate the interference between diagrams in a BSM model whose relevant part of the contributions are

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A&=[\bar{u}_e(k_2)v_e(k_3)] [\bar{u}_e(k_1)u_\mu(p_1)] \\
B&=[\bar{u}_e(k_1)\gamma_\mu v_e(k_2)] [\bar{v}_\mu(p_1)\gamma^\mu v_e(k_3)]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Using the polarization sum method, $AB^*+A^*B$ would be something like (ommiting spin indices)

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}\sum \text{tr}[(\displaystyle{\not}{k_1}+m_e)u_\mu(p_1) \bar{u}_e(k_2)(\displaystyle{\not}{k_3}-m_e)\gamma^\mu v_\mu(p_1)\bar{v}_e(k_2) \gamma_\mu]+\text{Complex Conjugate},
\end{equation}
using $\sum u(p,m)\bar{u}(p,m)=\displaystyle{\not}{p}+m$ and $\sum v(p,m)\bar{v}(p,m)=\displaystyle{\not}{p}-m$

I don't see how to eliminate the remaining spinors in the above equation and would guess the result is zero, but I checked computionally and the result seems to be

\begin{equation}
\text{tr}[(\displaystyle{\not}{p_1}+m_\mu)\gamma^\mu (-\displaystyle{\not}{k_3}-m_e) (\displaystyle{\not}{k_2}-m_e)\gamma_\mu (\displaystyle{\not}{k_1}+m_e)]
\end{equation}

I have also tried to figure this out writing the spinor indices explicitly, but it did not help me.

How to carry this calculation? Would I need to use crossing? Or is the computational result itself wrong? Details are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: the trick is simply to transpose the subchains (which are numbers) and use $u=v^c=C\bar{v}^T$ (which implies $\bar{v}^T=-Cu$ and $v^TC=\bar{u}$) and $C^{-1}\gamma_\mu^T C=-\gamma_\mu$.